# How can I plot times series EVI in R

Tags: r

I'm using R and I would like to create an EVI index time series plot, EVI index vs time, but I would like to plot for a selected polygon (pixel based in centre of some polygon) within the area.

For my data, I have EVI for 5 years (2000, 2001, 2005, 2010), the dates is encoded year then day-of-year. For my shapefile, I have some polygons circle for all shapefile but not the same for all years for some shapefiles I have 30 polygons

first shapefile : 3 polygons

second shapefile : 30 polygons

[image]

[image]

my questions is :

1. Should I need to create a raster stack for all years, how can I do it?
2. How can I plot times series for my raster stack in centroid of all polygons because: For 2000 I have 3 polygon for my shapfile , for 2001 i have 60 polygons for my shapfile . How I can do it?
3. How can I extract the centroid values for polygons ? and plot times series in centroid ?

Comment: Questions requesting code or debugging of code require a [MCVE]. You should show what libraries you anticipate using and any coding you have already done. SO is not a "give me an example of X"-server.

Comment: okey i will edited my question